# How to periodically retrieve web content

Tags: api, web

I have an idea for a fun little service that relies on data from two web sources and needs to periodically check them for updates.

First, I need to check 30-40 twitter accounts every 5 minutes to look for new tweets.

If I detect a new tweet, I want to hit an existing (not mine) php address and see if that page has changed since the last time I checked it.

The problem is, my background is entirely in application development. I have no idea what technologies, languages, or frameworks I should look into.

I would really appreciate some advice on where to start.

Some notes that may or may not help - I develop on a Mac, and have used xcode exclusively until now. I am happy to run the service/script/whatever locally during development but would like to host it eventually. My background is in Objective-C and other OO languages. I have no experience of developing against an API, web development, unix scripting, or anything else, but am ready for a challenge.

Comment: You've tagged your question PHP, but I think this is a mistake, as your question appears to have little to do with PHP.  For what it's worth, if you're considering using it, I'd suggest not: it is inappropriate for your application because it doesn't have good support for long-running or periodically-running tasks.

Comment: file_get_contents, json, serialize :p

Comment: @jules - thanks - any suggestions for other tags that might be more appropriate?

Comment: Is the  server supposed to do this checks for tweets or the clients? In the first case you want to learn as said, cronjobs and phpcurl to make requests to the twitter api. If its supposed to run in the clients browser you want to use javascript with ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily achieve this by setting up a cron job. Cron jobs are task that get periodically called, e.g. daily, weekly, even minutely.

If you want to do more than just checking those two addresses, e.g. display some web pages, I recommend you to use a web framework like the PHP Zend Framework.

Comment: Thanks - I only need to check those links. OK, some extremely basic q's - A cron job is something I would write using terminal and add to some unix directory on my machine, right? Or are there more sophisticated tools I should check out? What language would I be learning? Presumably my cron job will be able to parse the response, store a file, maybe insert it in a local database, etc?

Comment: cron is just a scheduler, you just use it to run the php script at a given interval. the php scrip then does all the work. of course this assumes a *nix server not a windows one.

Comment: Any modern language can be used for a cron job, even Cocoa, it is just something like a scheduler. Just create a console application, use crond to execute it regularly, ???, profit :-)